# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token script.js:

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON file below that I saved as flipkart.json:

```
flipkart = '[{
       "signup1":
        { 
                "firstname":  "ravi",
                "lastname" :  "kota",
                "mobileno" :   9555558039,
                "DOB"      :  "19-Mar-1980",
                "emailid"  :  "kota.raavi@gmail.com",
                "password" :  "password"
           }}]';
```

And I wrote a Javascript file as can be seen below, which I saved as script.js:

```
function load()
{
  var mydata = JSON.parse(flipkart);
  //alert(mydata[0].firstname);
  //alert(mydata[0].lastname);
  alert(ravikota);

 }
```

And my HTML code is:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>askyb - Load JSON File Locally by Javascript Without 
    JQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Kota 
      Ravi\Desktop\rainbow\flipkart.json"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Kota 
   Ravi\Desktop\rainbow\script.js"></script>
   </head>
    <body onload="load()">
    askyb - Load JSON File Locally by Javascript Without JQuery
   </body>
</html>
```

When i am trying to open the html file in the same directory, the console of HTML gives the error as:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    script.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: flipkart is not defined
    at load (script.js:3)
    at onload (rainbow.html:7)
```

I would like to know why my `flipkart.json` file is not being identified by the console. Thank you.

Comment: Is the JSON wrapped in curly brackets like so, { 'flipkart' = '[]' }?

Comment: json doesn't allow allocation with `=` so it's the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid and if you want to include it without using Javascript, then you're technically just creating a file with an array of objects inside of it. JSON files cannot be included in the page like scripts and then be referenced as you're trying to accomplish.

Also, if you were to create it as valid JSON it would have to look more like this. But in your case, this won't solve the problem.

```
[
  {
    "signup1": {
      "firstname": "ravi",
      "lastname": "kota",
      "mobileno": 9555558039,
      "DOB": "19-Mar-1980",
      "emailid": "kota.raavi@gmail.com",
      "password": "password"
    }
  }
]
```

Let's fix up your code. Firstly, rename `flipkart.json` to `flipkart.js` and change the script include in your HTML to include it first:

```
flipkart = [{
       "signup1":
        { 
                "firstname":  "ravi",
                "lastname" :  "kota",
                "mobileno" :   9555558039,
                "DOB"      :  "19-Mar-1980",
                "emailid"  :  "kota.raavi@gmail.com",
                "password" :  "password"
           }}];
```

This will create a global variable called `flipkart` which can be accessed from other scripts and anywhere in your page. I recommend reading up on the downsides of global variables, your approach while it will work is flawed.

Inside of it, we are creating an array and populating it with an object. This is just a standard array and Javascript object, it's not JSON.

Then finally, inside of `script.js` replace this line `var mydata = JSON.parse(flipkart);` with `var mydata = flipkart;` or better yet, just reference `flipkart` directly without creating a `mydata` variable in your script.

Comment: actually i mentioned a piece of code, but my original file has 680 lines so i created a json file, but as per your suggestion it seems there is no .JSON file, should i insert all the code in flipkart.js file only?

Comment: Yeah. You want your data in a separate file, assigned to a variable. Then you want to include that file first (flipkart.js) and then the variable you created is accessible in subsequent scripts. You don't need the `JSON.parse` part as you're not parsing JSON.

Comment: but can't we load a .JSON file in the javascript and that same script in HTML through src address URL.